Keycloack in react tries to call admin/serverInfo with a non-admin user
React application uses keycloack-js and @react-keycloack/web with the hooks provided by the react wrapper. User logs in with a normal user and at random point keycloack tryes to pull info from admin/serverInfo. This causes the app to crash.
I have tryed to find where it calls this endpoint but cant find anything. Any suggestions?
Also, me being extremly unlucky, the guy who set up the keycloack for the project, left our company last week, and the issue arose today.
EDIT:
Logging in and logging out with an admin user changes the client-id in the url. Havent found the reason why.
